# How to imitate a sort event with animation using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a list of items, each containing a checkbox. When a checkbox is ticked I'd like that item to sort itself to the beginning of the list, preferably animating as if it were being dragged with the mouse (but without a mouse cursor).

Is this possible? I've had trouble triggering draggable/sortable events in the past. I'm open to alternate solutions, it just need to be obvious where the item has moved to.

Edit: I was originally trying to ask how to make this happen on a jQuery sortable() list, but I obviously didn't communicate that very well, so I've updated the question to match all the wonderful answers.

Comment: If the user can select only one checkbox at a time, there's no need for any "actual" sorting algorithm. Just move the newly ticked item to the beginning of the list.

Comment: It's a checkbox not a radio button: the user can select as many as they like. The idea is to move all checked items to the beginning so that they are grouped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to avetarman's second example, this fiddle doesn't wait for the newly checked box to reach the top before the other ones take their rightful place. Instead, they all get animated together:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/Y5Mdt/1/

Ultimately, it's all about giving the row you're moving an absolute position so that it can slide up over the other rows, while giving the necessary CSS attributes to those other rows so that they don't immediately jump out of place when the selected row is removed from the document flow with the absolute positioning. Once that is done, the selected row loses it's absolute positioning, but is appended to the beginning of the rows. This allows all the css to essentially be "reset", so that you can proceed selecting new rows.

Comment: Good job. You've spent your time on this, huh? :-)

Comment: When spending my time in the depths of Drupal module creation and theming, I need continuous 10 min breaks of either online chess or jQuery to keep blood flowing to my head :)

Comment: I'd also like to point out that if you get good at jQuery, a lot of jQuery UI no longer becomes necessary. I think it actually becomes easier to roll your own custom solutions than learn how a certain feature of jQuery UI works, and the results will often be code that you better understand, and functionality that is really tweaked to the exact specs you want.

Comment: Wow that does work really well! Unfortunately not what I meant to ask for (see updated question).

Comment: You mean that you should be able to drag them with the mouse for sorting as well?

Comment: Yes, that's the primary feature.

Comment: Just came across this and noticed that unchecking and then checking the first item in the list causes the item to disspaear, is this intentional? Apologies for the necro.

Comment: @Swires -- no, not intended behavior. I've updated it here to check the index of the row containing the checked element. If its index is 0, nothing happens. http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Mdt/46/

Answer (score 3):

Check this fiddle.
No plugin is used here.

http://jsfiddle.net/bN8x6/

Check this update as well. It uses relative positioning. So, during animation the placeholder is being kept.

http://jsfiddle.net/bN8x6/1/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery ui has a [transfer](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Transfer) animation.

Quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRtfj/1/) here.

You could use this to immitate the sort then on the callback move the actual checkbox. 
I will update the demo when I get home to use a list of checkboxes to do the sort.

Comment: 2021... the guy has probably got lost in *transfer* to home.

Comment: what are you on about?

Comment: *I will update the demo when I get home to use a list of checkboxes to do the sort*...

Comment: it was updated 10 years ago, jsfiddle obviously had an archive ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
$('#mytest li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.children("input:checked")) {
        $this.effect("transfer", {
            to: $this.parent().find(":first-child")
        }, 1000);
        $this.remove();
         $(this).prependTo("#mytest");
    }    
});
```

```css
.ui-effects-transfer {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="mytest">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">One</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">Two</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">Three</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check4" /><label for="check4">Four</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check5" /><label for="check5">Five</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check6" /><label for="check6">Six</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check7" /><label for="check7">Seven</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check8" /><label for="check8">Eight</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check9" /><label for="check9">Nine</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="check10" /><label for="check10">Ten</label></li>
</ul>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/gLBjt/

Disclaimer: This is essentially a port of @redsquare solution. :)